# Pandas : Confused when extending DataFrame vs Series (Column/Index). Why the difference?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

First off, let me say that I've already looked over various responses to similar questions, but so far, none of them has really made it clear to me why (or why not) the Series and DataFrame methodologies are different.
Also, some of the Pandas information is not clear, for example looking up Series.reindex,
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html
all the examples suddenly switch to showing examples for DataFrame not Series, but the functions don't seem to overlap exactly.

So, now to it, first with a DataFrame.

```
> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=range(6), columns=list('ABCD'))
> df
Out[544]: 
          A         B         C         D
0  0.136833 -0.974500  1.708944  0.435174
1 -0.357955 -0.775882 -0.208945  0.120617
2 -0.002479  0.508927 -0.826698 -0.904927
3  1.955611 -0.558453 -0.476321  1.043139
4 -0.399369 -0.361136 -0.096981  0.092468
5 -0.130769 -0.075684  0.788455  1.640398
```

Now,  to add new columns,  I can do something simple (2 ways, same result).

```
> df[['X','Y']] = (99,-99)
> df.loc[:,['X','Y']] = (99,-99)
> df
Out[557]: 
          A         B         C         D   X   Y
0  0.858615 -0.552171  1.225210 -1.700594  99 -99
1  1.062435 -1.917314  1.160043 -0.058348  99 -99
2  0.023910  1.262706 -1.924022 -0.625969  99 -99
3  1.794365  0.146491 -0.103081  0.731110  99 -99
4 -1.163691  1.429924 -0.194034  0.407508  99 -99
5  0.444909 -0.905060  0.983487 -4.149244  99 -99
```

Now, with a Series, I have hit a (mental?) block trying the same.
I'm going to be using a loop to construct a list of Series that will eventually be a data frame,  but I want to deal with each 'row' as a Series first, (to make development easier).

```
> ss = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=list('ABCD'))
> ss
Out[552]: 
A    0.078013
B    1.707052
C   -0.177543
D   -1.072017
dtype: float64

> ss['X','Y'] = (99,-99)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
KeyError: "None of [Index(['X', 'Y'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Same for,

```
> ss[['X','Y']] = (99,-99)
> ss.loc[['X','Y']] = (99,-99)
KeyError: "None of [Index(['X', 'Y'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

The only way I can get this working is a rather clumsy (IMHO),

```
> ss['X'],ss['Y'] = (99,-99)
> ss
Out[560]: 
A     0.078013
B     1.707052
C    -0.177543
D    -1.072017
X    99.000000
Y   -99.000000
dtype: float64
```

I did think that, perhaps, reindexing the Series to add the new indices prior to assignment might solve to problem.  It would, but then I hit an issue trying to change the index.

```
> ss = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=list('ABCD'), name='z')
> xs = pd.Series([99,-99], index=['X','Y'], name='z')
```

Here I can concat my 2 Series to create a new one, and I can also concat the Series indices, eg,

```
> ss.index.append(xs.index)
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'Y'], dtype='object')
```

But I can't extend the current index with,

```
> ss.index = ss.index.append(xs.index)
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

So, what intuitive leap must I make to understand why the former Series methods don't work, but (what looks like an equivalent) DataFrame method does work?
It makes passing multiple outputs back from a function into new Series elements a bit clunky.  I can't 'on the fly' make up new Series index names to insert values into my exiting Series object.

Comment: There is discussion in pandas github, for me seems bug - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7887 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15747

Comment: @jezrael, Thanks for the insight links.  So perhaps I'm not the only one not grapsing the 'rules',  A bit heavy, so I'll only say that I believe that User expectations (i.e. me), would be that a behavoiur in a 1D DataFrame would be equivalent (as much as possible) to the same behaviour in a Series.

Comment: Absolutely agree, so it was reason why I think it is bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can directly modify the Series in place to add multiple values at once.

If having a new object is not an issue:

```
ss = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=list('ABCD'), name='z')
xs = pd.Series([99,-99], index=['X','Y'], name='z')

# new object with updated index
ss = ss.reindex(ss.index.union(xs.index))
ss.update(xs)
```

Output:

```
A    -0.369182
B    -0.239379
C     1.099660
D     0.655264
X    99.000000
Y   -99.000000
Name: z, dtype: float64
```

##### *in place* alternative using a function:

```
ss = pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=list('ABCD'), name='z')
xs = pd.Series([99,-99], index=['X','Y'], name='z')

def extend(s1, s2):
    s1.update(s2) # update common indices
    # add others
    for idx, val in s2[s2.index.difference(s1.index)].items():
        s1[idx] = val
        
extend(ss, xs)
```

Updated `ss`:

```
A     0.279925
B    -0.098150
C     0.910179
D     0.317218
X    99.000000
Y   -99.000000
Name: z, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think that, ultimately, as you suggest, the only way out is to override the existing Series with a new version of the 'wanted' Series.
Going for the cleanest way (at least for Series objects) is to use pd.concat I think, so,
`ss = pd.concat([ss, xs])` would seem the easiest.
It doesn't help for assigning a list into an extended series though, except by making it a Series.

Comment: @JohnT if you have no overlapping indices yes, `concat` is the easiest, otherwise you'll have duplicates ;)

Comment: I do like your use of `ss.index.union()`, you were thinking a bit wider than I was and considering the possible problem of overlapping index names, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tried to write code that would mimic what would happen if `ss.loc[['X','Y']] = (99,-99)` was accepting non-existing indices ;)

Answer (score 2):

While I have accepted @mozway's answer above since it nicely handles extending the Series even when there are possible index conflicts, I'm adding this 'answer' to demonstrate my point about the inconsistency in the extend operation between Series and DataFrame.

If I create my Series as single row DataFrames, as below, I can now extend the 'series' as I expected.

```
z=pd.Index(['z'])
ss = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,4), columns=list('ABCD'),index=z)
xs = pd.DataFrame([[99,-99]], columns=['X','Y'],index=z)

ss
Out[619]: 
          A         B         C         D
z  1.052589 -0.337622 -0.791994 -0.266888
ss[['x','y']] = xs
ss
Out[620]: 
          A         B         C         D   x   y
z  1.052589 -0.337622 -0.791994 -0.266888  99 -99
type(ss)
Out[621]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Note that, as a DataFrame, I don't even need a Series for the extend object.

```
ss[['X','Y']] = [123,-123]

ss
Out[633]: 
          A         B         C         D    X    Y
z  0.600981 -0.473031  0.216941  0.255252  123 -123
```

So I've simply extended the DataFrame, but it's still a DataFrame of 1 row.
I can now either 'squeeze' the DataFrame,

```
zz1=ss.squeeze()

type(zz1)
Out[624]: pandas.core.series.Series
zz1
Out[625]: 
A     1.052589
B    -0.337622
C    -0.791994
D    -0.266888
x    99.000000
y   -99.000000
Name: z, dtype: float64
```

Alternatively, I can use 'iloc[0]' to get a Series directly. Note that 'loc' will return a DataFrame not a Series and will still require 'squeezing'.

```
zz2=ss.iloc[0]

type(zz2)
Out[629]: pandas.core.series.Series

zz2
Out[630]: 
A     1.052589
B    -0.337622
C    -0.791994
D    -0.266888
x    99.000000
y   -99.000000
Name: z, dtype: float64
```

Please note, I'm not a Pandas 'wizard' so there may be other insights that I lack.